# HttpListenerRequest Encoding ignores ContentType charset defined

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm running a HttpListener in a c# app, that receives a HTTP GET request, with following defined

```
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

According to the MSDN document for [ContentEncoding property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.contentencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), following is described:

> An Encoding object can be used to convert byte sequences into character sets (code pages) and characters into byte sequences. **This property uses the charset value from the Content-Type header to determine the encoding**. If that information is not available, this property returns Encoding.Default.

When I look at the Content-Encoding property of the request, it still return default ISO instead of the defined UTF-8 encoding.

Am I missing something, or is this property just toally bugged from MS site??

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if you doesn't set a Content-Lenght in your request, then HttpListener will bypass the charset of Content-Type, leading to the issue that I described in the question. The solution is to set Content-Lenght to at least 1 (In PostMan this header is restricted, so the work-around in there, is to add a whitespace in the body. I don't know a work-around for get requests yet).